# Postgresql select where one of two columns in set

Tags: sql, postgresql

My tables :

- R1(id serial, a int , b int) - 100k records
- R2(id,serial,VAL unique) - 40k records

Indexes : r2(VAL),r1(a),r1(b)

My goal : get all records from R1 where a or b equals VAL in R2

I thought about 2 options :

```
select * from R1 where R1.a in (select VAL from R2) or R1.b in (select VAL from R2);
```

or

```
select * from R1 where exists (select * from R2 where R1.a = R2.VAL or R1.b = R2.VAL);
```

In my specific case:

- The first query uses seq scan on R1 and hash scan on r2.
- The second scan uses seq scan on R1 and bitmap scan on r2 with the index R2(VAL).

I wanted to hear if I can rewrite the query in a better way in order to gain performance. By the way I'm using pg 9.6

Thanks..

Comment: I'd try `SELECT r1.* FROM r1 JOIN r2 ON (r1.a = r2.val OR r1.b = r2.val);` - I don't know whether it's faster than anything but it seems to be the cleanest SQL expression

Comment: …except that it returns a row twice if both `a` and `b` appear in `r2`, to prevent that you'd need to throw in a `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in this specific case the first query I suggested in my main comment provides the best performance :

```
select * from R1 where R1.a in (select VAL from R2) or R1.b in (select VAL from R2);
```

@klin prepared a dbfiddle with all the execution plans if someone want to have a look : 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=5b50f605262e406c0bab13710ec121d5

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
select r1.*
from R1
where exists (select 1 from r2 where r1.a = r2.val) or
      exists (select 1 from r2 where r1.b = r2.val);
```

Then, you want an index on `r2(val)`.

If `r2` is *really* small and `r1` is *really* big and there are separate indexes on `r1(a)` and `r1(b)`, then this might be faster:

```
select r1.*
from r1 join
     r2
     on r1.a = r2.val
union
select r1.*
from r1 join
     r2
     on r1.b = r2.val;
```

Comment: How is your 1st query better than the OP's: `select * from R1 where exists (select * from R2 where R1.a = R2.VAL or R1.b = R2.VAL);`?

Comment: @forpas . . . I don't know how Postgres behaves in using indexes with the `or` in the `where` clause.  There might be cases where it doesn't use an appropriate index.

Comment: So this query should stand as a test case and not a recommendation.

Comment: @forpas - Whatever you want to call it, the first query seems to be the best in most cases.

Comment: @klin EXISTS twice? I don't think so. But, I might be wrong, this is why I call it a test case.

Comment: @forpas - The two `exists` use two very fast index only scans while `exists(... or ...)` needs BitmapOr.

Comment: According to the execution plan , the first option that I suggested in my main post is better. The first query that u suggested, use a seq scan on r1 and Index only scan on r2. The second query u suggested looks good in aspect of performance but is still takes more time than my first query.

Comment: Out of curiosity: [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=5b50f605262e406c0bab13710ec121d5)

Answer (score 0):

And how about

```
select * from r1 join r2 on r1.a=r2.val
union
select * from r1 join r2 on r1.b=r2.val
```

?

Comment: it doesnt look good, requires two seq scans on r1 and two hash scans on r2

Comment: I don't agree with the union_all - because if a and b end up being same value you'll get duplicate records....

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) that returns all the `VAL`s from `R2` (so you scan `R2` only once).
But maybe this is not needed if the optimizer does it already for `select VAL from R2`.
 
Then use `CASE` to check the 2 separate cases, so the 2nd case (`WHEN b IN (SELECT VAL FROM cte)`) will be evaluated only when the 1st case (`WHEN a IN (SELECT VAL FROM cte)`) fails.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT VAL FROM R2)
SELECT * FROM R1
WHERE 1 = CASE
  WHEN a IN (SELECT VAL FROM cte) THEN 1
  WHEN b IN (SELECT VAL FROM cte) THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: This is the closest query in aspect of performance`s cost to my first query. This query cost is 4658 while my first query`s cost is 3385.